# Forcing footer to bottom of page, if document height is smaller than window height

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, footer

I'm working on fixing the display of my website in ipad's portrait mode. The issue is that the page length isn't as long as the ipad's portrait display. Here is a pic of what I'm talking about:

[image]

I created a jQuery function that I thought would detect when the document height isn't as big as the window height, which then I could set the position of the footer to fixed. Here is my code:

```
if ($(document).height() < $(window).height()) {
    $('#footer-wrapper').attr('style', 'position: fixed!important; bottom: 0px;');
}
```

Current CSS:

```
#footer-wrapper {
    padding: 20px 0px 23px;
    background-color: #E3E9DC;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #007897;
    border-top: 3px solid #007897;
    color: #585858;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #footer-wrapper {
        /*padding: 20px 0px 23px;*/
        background-color: #E3E9DC;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #007897;
        border-top: 3px solid #007897;
        color: #585858;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: -65px!important;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

I think this could work, but for some reason the document is saying that its height is bigger than the window viewport, so the if statement isn't executed. Does anyone know a more reliable way of achieving this?

Comment: That's called a "sticky footer", and you can do it with CSS alone. E.g. http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-auto-height.htm

Comment: I know its called a sticky footer, but I don't want it to be sticky or fixed to the bottom at all times. I only want it to kick in when the entire <body> doesn't reach to the bottom of the page (as shown in the ipad pic). The site looks great in everything else already.

Comment: The easy alternative (and my preference) is to make the body background the same as the footer color. (You just have to set any other content area backgrounds explicitly, like when you have a white content area).

Answer (score 6):

simply change javascript to:

```
if ($(document.body).height() < $(window).height()) {
  $('#footer-wrapper').attr('style', 'position: fixed!important; bottom: 0px;');
}
```

Comment: I had to change `if ($(document.body).height() < $(window).height()) {` to `if ($(document.body).height() <= $(window).height()) {` - just changing < to <=, otherrwise they would be equal when the page was shorter than the window, for whatever reason it's calculated like that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately body height can be set to 100%. Here is the solution dealing only  with footer

```
$(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
    var f = $('#footer-wrapper');
    f.css({position:'static'});
    if (f.offset().top + f.height() < $(window).height()) {
        f.css({position:'fixed', bottom:'0', width:'100%'});
    }
});
```