# Check if window height is greater than div#content height in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'd like to add css styles (position: fixed) to footer only if window.height is greater than height of div with main content.

In my solution (below) the condition is always true, so it dosn't work as I expect. Moreover I'm not sure if I used $scope.$watch in right way to control window height - I don't want to press f5 every time when I change page (eg. form home page to contact page) to refresh scope and apply additional styles.

I've found similar topics (eg. [Forcing footer to bottom of page, if document height is smaller than window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095645/forcing-footer-to-bottom-of-page-if-document-height-is-smaller-than-window-heig) ) but nothing for AngularJS

I'm using AngularJS 1.6. 
This is my code:

```
controllersFooter.controller( 'footer' , [ '$scope' , '$window' , function( $scope , $window  ){

var $footer = angular.element(document.querySelector('#site-footer'));
$scope.windowHeight = jQuery( window ).height();

$window.onload = function() {

    $scope.$watch(function(){
        var contentHeight = document.getElementById('content-container').scrollHeight;
        return contentHeight;
    }, function(value){

        var contentHeight = value;

        if ( contentHeight < $scope.windowHeight ) {
            $footer.css(
            {
              "position":"fixed",
              "bottom":0,
              "left": 0,
              "right": 0
            }
          );
        }
    });

}; }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class in the footer with a scope variable and make it true or false according the height of the page 
More about ng-class 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

## 1

Please make sure that the document body has a scroll.

Just it can be any other div with `overflow: auto`... you expect that it will be document.body, but that is not always true

## 2

I advice you to just subscribe to scroll event on element with scroll-bar, like:

```
jQuery( elementWithScrollBar ).scroll(function() {
  $scope.fixed = calculateIfFooterIsFixed();
  $scope.$digest(); // run angular digest cycle to reflect scope changes to DOM,
                    // most likely you will need it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Event on windows resize is available natively in angularjs.

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', this.onResize);
```

In your case for example sth like that:

```
var footerHeight = document.getElementById('side-footer').scrollHeight;
this.onResize = function() {
    var contentHeight = document.getElementById('content-container').scrollHeight;
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.isFixed = contentHeight > $window.innerHeight - footerHeight
    });
}
```

and use ng-class:

```
  <div id="side-footer" ng-class="{'fixed': isFixed}">
```

Position "fixed" when main content is smaller than visible window:
https://jsfiddle.net/UncleGoogle/jpy4zse9/25/
(for some reason need to run twice to set fiddle footer size properly)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your work, but I have few doubts. 
Firstly, you've defined #content-container height in css (in your eg it's 240px). But height for content container should depend on content and it'll be different for each page. That why I can't add css's property height with static value to content-container.
Secondly, if you'll go form page A to page B to check content height you neet to refresh page using F5.

Comment: Hi, it is not a problem that height is set dynamically. css is just 'property'. The only issue is that you need to call you controller method on page change or, containter change or whatever you need. If these containters has their own controllers, they can communicate using $scope.$broadcast or shared service. If you edit you original post and paste some html pattern you have && write down structure of your code (related controllers, services), being precise I will try to solve that in the next week.