# fit footer image for all screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I have the below code of the footer :**

```html
<div class="footer footer-content">
    <div class="content-logo login">
        <span><img src="${url.resourcesPath}/img/logoSample1.png" alt="Logo" /></span>
    </div>      
</div>
```

**here is the CSS:**

```css
div.footer {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 65vh;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}


.footer {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('../img/myImage.jpg');
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 9%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 9%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.content-logo.login {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /*  margin-top: 2rem;*/
}

.content-logo {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

***Image 1:***

[image]

***Image 2:***

[image]

***My question:***

**As I test in different devices, as can be seen in image-2 the footer doesnt fit/stays at the bottom on different screen sizes, It cuts the logo and the footer moves up, showing the background colour at bottom. I am able to fit the image by changing the height in above CSS (for example, chnaging in above CSS from "height: 65vh;" to "height: 35vh;" for a mobile screen) to the view port height of different screen sizes, but thats not good as screen sizes can be anything. how can I fit the footer at bottom with logo floating at the bottom right corner irrespective of any screen size ? Its okay if the image gets stretched, the logo should show up in every screen. I am stuck, appreciate all the help here.**

Link to footer image just incase : https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSpblwwG6gPo00z3cP_4c-lgit81chm13PZjHOxHBlQrGcp3EAuYSEeGj7YCgP510fn3g&usqp=CAU

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is caused because the content of your website is lower than browser's window height.

Check this topic, there is an image that helps you to visualize this issue:
[Forcing footer to bottom of page, if document height is smaller than window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095645/forcing-footer-to-bottom-of-page-if-document-height-is-smaller-than-window-heig)

To resolve this issue you can set `min-height` for the middle part of the page to 100% of window height - header height - footer height. Thanks to this middle part of the page will fill available space in height.

```
div {
  min-height: calc(100vh - {header height} - {footer height});
}
```

or you can add `position: fixed;` to footer image to put it at the bottom of the page and add some `padding` at the bottom of `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` and `left: 0` to your `footer` class in `CSS` code, and check if the problem still occurs:

```css
div.footer {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 65vh;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}


.footer {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSpblwwG6gPo00z3cP_4c-lgit81chm13PZjHOxHBlQrGcp3EAuYSEeGj7YCgP510fn3g&usqp=CAU');
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 9%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 9%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.content-logo.login {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /*  margin-top: 2rem;*/
}

.content-logo {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer footer-content">
    <div class="content-logo login">
        <span><img src="${url.resourcesPath}/img/logoSample1.png" alt="Logo" /></span>
    </div>      
</div>
```